# store integer value into android database

Tags: android, database, integer

In android, how can get I get a value (that is of type integer) from `EditText` and insert it into database that has a integer field?

I am using the below code but it doesn't save integer data into database!

```
EditText Price;
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_GoodsName);
Price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_Price);
db.insertQuote(name.getText().toString(),Price.getText());

// ----------------------------------------------------------

public long insertQuote(String Quote,int Price1) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(GoodName, Quote);
    initialValues.put(Price, Price1);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible, may be you had given wrong `fieldname` or `tablename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
db.insertQuote(name.getText().toString(),Integer.valueOf(Price.getText().toString()));
```

or

```
db.insertQuote(name.getText().toString(),new Integer(Price.getText().toString()));
```

instead of

```
 db.insertQuote(name.getText().toString(),Price.getText());
```

because `db.insertQuote(String,Integer)` accept second parameter as Integer not as String.

Comment: :i use your code but it doesn t save data in database!!!if i don t use integer value and just save first parametr it works!!!!but when i want to save integer(even with your soloution it doesn t work)

Comment: @shadi :   both options in answer are right to convert an String to Integer.maybe you have some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to parse String to int because in function second parameter is int not string.

```
db.insertQuote(name.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(Price.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: No, using `ContentValues` this problem will not occur.

Comment: @hotveryspicy : i agree with you but he is passing String as Integer to function insertQuote not to ContentValues

Comment: Then you must tell him the reason for calling wrong parameter in function rather providing the direct solution.